# Не могу понять, объясните пожалуйста код

Tags: java

Если выполнить следующий код, то результатом будет = 1, 1, 2

Не могу понять почему именно еденицы печатаются...

```
public class Test {
    private final static BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");


    private void inc1(BigInteger d) {
        d.add(one);
    }

    private void inc2(BigInteger d) {
        d = d.add(one);
    }

    private BigInteger inc3(BigInteger d) {
        return d.add(one);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();

        BigInteger a = new BigInteger("1");
        t.inc1(a);
        System.out.println(a);

        BigInteger b = new BigInteger("1");
        t.inc2(b);
        System.out.println(b);

        BigInteger c = new BigInteger("1");
        System.out.println(t.inc3(c));

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- inc1 - Вы не возвращаете результат `d.add(one)`
- inc2 - Вы только перезаписываете локальную переменную `d` с результатом
- inc3 - здесь Вы возвращаете вычисленное значение, это работает

Метод `add` не изменяет текущий объект- он возвращает новый объект с вычисленным значением.

Также нет смысла называть переменную "one", когда в ней может быть значение 2.

Еще можно использовать константы `BigInteger.ZERO`, `BigInteger.ONE`, `BigInteger.TWO`, ..

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 3):

В классе Test: методы inc1 и inc2 - аналогичны, они лишь увеличивают свою локальную переменную, которая при завершении функции стерается, не возвращая её, поэтому в main(вызывающей эти методы функции) переменные a и b не изменяются. inc3 же увеличивает данную ему переменную и возвращает её, поэтому в main переменная c увеличится.